# Javascript draw line script not working

Tags: javascript, html, line

Tested in Firefox and Chrome.  Script found on SO in an old Q/A.  Script claimed to be working, doesn't work for me.  Would rather use pure JS to solve this problem instead of HTML5 canvas to support older browsers.

jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/qnkonmgo/

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

window.onload = function() {
    DrawLine(1,1,100,100);
}

function DrawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2){

    if(y1 < y2){
        var pom = y1;
        y1 = y2;
        y2 = pom;
        pom = x1;
        x1 = x2;
        x2 = pom;
    }

    var a = Math.abs(x1-x2);
    var b = Math.abs(y1-y2);
    var c;
    var sx = (x1+x2)/2 ;
    var sy = (y1+y2)/2 ;
    var width = Math.sqrt(a*a + b*b ) ;
    var x = sx - width/2;
    var y = sy;

    a = width / 2;

    c = Math.abs(sx-x);

    b = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(x1-x)*Math.abs(x1-x)+Math.abs(y1-y)*Math.abs(y1-y) );

    var cosb = (b*b - a*a - c*c) / (2*a*c);
    var rad = Math.acos(cosb);
    var deg = (rad*180)/Math.PI

    htmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
    div = document.createElementNS(htmlns, "div");
    div.setAttribute('style','border:1px solid black;width:'+width+'px;height:0px;-moz-transform:rotate('+deg+'deg);-webkit-transform:rotate('+deg+'deg);position:absolute;top:'+y+'px;left:'+x+'px;');  
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This snippet actually isn't supported in older browsers, it uses some CSS3 styles. Also, please define "doesn't work".

Comment: `div` is just an in memory object, make last line `document.body.appendChild(div);`

Comment: Thank you Alex K.  Was just confused because that script was upvoted a ton and praised by a few people, yet it didn't contain that line...

Comment: Probably because this script uses global variable `div` which refers to element that is already in DOM.

Answer (score 1):

This works.  See the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jvs9hLwf/1/

```
(function DrawLine(elementId, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    if (y1 < y2) {
        var pom = y1;
        y1 = y2;
        y2 = pom;
        pom = x1;
        x1 = x2;
        x2 = pom;
    }
    var a = Math.abs(x1 - x2);
    var b = Math.abs(y1 - y2);
    var c;
    var sx = (x1 + x2) / 2;
    var sy = (y1 + y2) / 2;
    var width = Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b);
    var x = sx - width / 2;
    var y = sy;
    a = width / 2;
    c = Math.abs(sx - x);
    b = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(x1 - x) * Math.abs(x1 - x) + Math.abs(y1 - y) * Math.abs(y1 - y));
    var cosb = (b * b - a * a - c * c) / (2 * a * c);
    var rad = Math.acos(cosb);
    var deg = (rad * 180) / Math.PI
    div = document.getElementById(elementId);
    div.setAttribute('style', 'border:1px solid black;width:' + width + 'px;height:0px;-moz-transform:rotate(' + deg + 'deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(' + deg + 'deg);position:absolute;top:' + y + 'px;left:' + x + 'px;');
})("div", 1, 1, 100, 100);
```

First - instead of putting it in a window.onload event, I immediately invoke the function with the desired parameters, but kept the function name so that it can be reused.

Second - I've added in a parameter so you can specify the element ID that you are trying to draw the line in when you call the function.

Comment: Or just what Alex says withoug specifying element ID.