# Pure Javascript drawing a triangle, positioning hypotenuse

Tags: javascript, html, css, geometry, drawing

I have 3 x,y points that I am trying to use to draw a right trangle.  So I am calculating the angles of the triangle after calculating side lengths.  After I have gotten the hypotenuse's length, I want to rotate the hypotenuse so that it completes the triangle.  For some reason, my hypotenuse is a bit out of position even though it is rotated the appropriate amount of degrees.  Here is my code and a jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/kn5zk54c/

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

window.onload = function() {
//drawTriangle(1,1,100,1,100,100);
drawTriangle(1,1,100,1,1,100);
}


function drawTriangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3) {

//The length of side a is the difference between point 1 and point 2's x (horizonal) axis.
var a = Math.abs(x1 - x2);

//The length of side b is the difference between point 2 and point 3's y (veritcal axis)
var b = Math.abs(y2 - y3);

//Too find the length of the last side c, we must use the pythagorean theorem.
//c*c=a*a+b*b
//square side a and b, and add the result.  Then find the square root of the result.
var c = Math.sqrt(((a*a) + (b*b)));

//We must use the Cosine rule to solve the triangles 3 angles.
//c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - c^2 

var A = (Math.acos(((c*c)+(b*b)-(a*a))/(2*c*b)))*(180/Math.PI);
var B = (Math.acos(((c*c)+(a*a)-(b*b))/(2*a*c)))*(180/Math.PI); 
var C = (Math.acos(((a*a)+(b*b)-(c*c))/(2*a*b)))*(180/Math.PI);


//Add side A div between points x1,y1, and x2,y2
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.style.height = '1px';
div.style.width = a + 'px';
div.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
div.style.position = "absolute";
div.style.left = x1;
div.style.top = y1;
document.body.appendChild(div);

//Add side B div between points x2,y2 and x3,y3
div = document.createElement('div');
div.style.height = b + "px";
div.style.width = "1px";
div.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
div.style.position = "absolute";
div.style.left = x2;
div.style.top = y2;
document.body.appendChild(div);

div = document.createElement('div');
div.style.height = "1px";
div.style.width = c + "px";
div.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
div.style.position = "absolute";
div.style.left = x3;
div.style.top = y3;

div.style.transform = "rotate(45deg)";

document.body.appendChild(div);

}

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've to set [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) correctly.

Comment: Ok thanks Teemu, where should I set the point of origin of the transformation to form the triangle.

Comment: You are not setting units for the top and left. Add "px" to the values.

`div.style.left = x1 + "px";
div.style.top = y1 + "px";`

Comment: Just made the change, and the hypotenuse is still not positioned to connect points A and C.  I am reading about transform-origin but not sure what to put for the point of origin for the transformation to make the sides line up and form the trangle.

Comment: The top left corner is prob where you want the origin, but then you have to move the div so the it starts at the bottom.  Think of the origin like where it will pivot.

Comment: transform-origin:120px 50px works for this particular triangle but you would need to work out the relationship of that when dealing with others http://jsfiddle.net/kn5zk54c/3/

Comment: Thanks tbh, I tried setting the point of origin for the transformation like so to the top left corner of the triangle, and it completely dissapeared.

div.style.transformOrigin = x1 + " " y1;

Comment: Just tried those numbers like so, Quinoa

div.style.transformOrigin = "120px 50px";

And my hypotenuse is still not positioned correctly.  Although I see it is in the jsfiddle you posted, I'll take a look at the code there.

Comment: yeah in the fiddle the top and left haven't been applied (as per @epascarello's comment) with the top and left applied they become something like -38px 114px

Comment: For some reason even when I copy and paste the code from the JSFiddle you posted into Sublime Text 2 and save it to my local HDD, and run it in Google Chrome and Firefox, the hypotenuse is still out of posiition.  Yet on the jsfiddle page, it looks like a nice right triangle.

Comment: Notice, what epascarello has commented. Without units setting any position or size is ignored. All the position properties lack an unit in your code. As I've commented to your earlier question, this is not going to work in older browsers. You might get some ideas, how to add some "DIV graphics" on a page from Walter Zorn's [JSGraphic Library](http://www.walterzorn.de/en/jsgraphics/jsgraphics_e.htm).

Comment: I added the units Teemu, like this div.style.left = x1 + "px";
div.style.top = y1 + "px"; and the hypotenuse is still off.  But I think the answer has to do with transform-origin like you said, just not sure what the point of origin for the transformation should be.  I tried one post here and also didn't work in Chrome or Firefox for me.

Comment: Do you think using HTML 5 canvas is better Teemu, compared to using a 3rd party JS library like the one you linked, I appreciate it by the way.

Comment: Yes, use it if possible. In [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26530983/1169519) I've referred above, you've stated: "... instead of HTML5 canvas to support older browsers." However, CSS3 is not supported in older browsers either (including `transform`). Using canvas (or a library when canvas not supported) would just make your life much easier ; ).

Comment: I've gotten very close to having the hypotenuse position itself properly through trial and error using transform-origin using div.style.transformOrigin = "1px 1px";  But still not quite perfect.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking, why use CSS3 styles which is going to limit me to newer browsers anyways, should probably just use HTML5 canvas if I'm going to use CSS3.  I was just hoping to be able to accomplish this and not limit the amount of browsers that can view it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So as @epascarello commented the top and left are not being taken into account so first thing is to add 
"px" to the values there, this breaks the triangle though so in the example below I have restructured what the top and left are being set as, the first two lines come form the same point(x1 y1) the last comes from the end of line 2 (x2 y2). To get the angle right over rotate it to 135deg and set the transformation origin as 0px 0px so that it then rotates in to the right place.

Having said all this you would find more consistent results using something like canvas.

**EDIT**
actually just realised the triangle is the wrong way round as the last point is 100,100. (was trying to make it look like the one from your fiddle and ignoring what the points were saying, updated the example below so each line uses the correct points and over rotated the last to 225deg)

```js
window.onload = function() {
  drawTriangle(1, 1, 100, 1, 100, 100);
}


function drawTriangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3) {

  //The length of side a is the difference between point 1 and point 2's x (horizonal) axis.
  var a = Math.abs(x1 - x2);

  //The length of side b is the difference between point 2 and point 3's y (veritcal axis)
  var b = Math.abs(y2 - y3);

  //Too find the length of the last side c, we must use the pythagorean theorem.
  //c*c=a*a+b*b
  //square side a and b, and add the result.  Then find the square root of the result.
  var c = Math.sqrt(((a * a) + (b * b)));

  //We must use the Cosine rule to solve the triangles 3 angles.
  //c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - c^2 

  var A = (Math.acos(((c * c) + (b * b) - (a * a)) / (2 * c * b))) * (180 / Math.PI);
  var B = (Math.acos(((c * c) + (a * a) - (b * b)) / (2 * a * c))) * (180 / Math.PI);
  var C = (Math.acos(((a * a) + (b * b) - (c * c)) / (2 * a * b))) * (180 / Math.PI);


  //Add side a.
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.height = '1px';
  div.style.width = a + 'px';
  div.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
  div.style.position = "absolute";
  div.style.left = x1 + "px";
  div.style.top = y1 + "px";
  document.body.appendChild(div);

  //Add side b.
  div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.height = b + "px";
  div.style.width = "1px";
  div.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
  div.style.position = "absolute";
  div.style.left = x2 + "px";
  div.style.top = y2 + "px";
  document.body.appendChild(div);
  //Add side c.
  div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.height = "1px";
  div.style.width = c + "px";
  div.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
  div.style.position = "absolute";
  div.style.left = x3 + "px";
  div.style.top = y3 + "px";
  div.style.transform = "rotate(225deg)";
  div.style.transformOrigin = "0px 0px";

  document.body.appendChild(div);

}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, it's helpful.  But 1 quick question, I would think point C (x3,y3) should be over 100px to the left, since the call to the DrawTriangle function is as follows.

  drawTriangle(1, 1, 100, 1, 100, 100);

But instead x3 and y3 seem to be graphed at around 1,100.  Just curious why C seems to be on the opposite side where I would expect it considering the hardcoded input arguments for drawTriangle.

Comment: I marked it as the answer after your update,  this was the desired result based on the point C being placed at 100,100.  Any tips on calculating how many degrees of rotation I will need if instead x3 and y3 was set to 100,200?

Comment: just comes down to some more math, found a nice looking resource http://www.teacherschoice.com.au/maths_library/trigonometry/solve_trig_sss.htm, just remember though that you want the outside angle to do the rotation with not the inside angle

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle example, when I use x2=200, y2=1 and x3=100,y3=200 as input values in draw triangle.  side c, the hypotenuse, is out of position again.  http://jsfiddle.net/jwc62eL4/

Comment: in this fiddle the px are still missing from top and left

Comment: Sorry think I posted an older jsFiddle link the first time, I edited it with new input values and also in the updated link I am adding +"px"; to the top and left positions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63725/discussion-between-quince-and-david-stampher).

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to create any kind of triangles using `DIV`s and `transform rotate()`:

```js
function drawLine (p1, p2, stroke, color) {
    var dx = p2[0] - p1[0], // Horizontal distance
        dy = p2[1] - p1[1], // Vertical distance
        angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx) * (180 / Math.PI), // Angle related to X-axis
        length = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy), // Line length
        div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.position = "absolute";
    div.style.left = p1[0] + 'px'; // Set position to p1 using
    div.style.top = p1[1] - stroke / 2 + 'px'; // line weight correction
    div.style.width = length + 'px'; // width as line length
    div.style.height = stroke + 'px'; // height as line weight
    div.style.background = color;
    div.style.transformOrigin = '0% 50%'; // Set origin to 50% of line weight
    div.style.transform = 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg)';
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}

function drawTriangle (P1, P2, P3, stroke, color) {
    drawLine(P1, P2, stroke, color);
    drawLine(P2, P3, stroke, color);
    drawLine(P3, P1, stroke, color);
}

drawTriangle([10, 100], [60, 10], [110, 100], 10, 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)');
drawTriangle([120, 10], [220, 10], [170, 100], 10, 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)');
drawTriangle([100, 150], [200, 200], [150, 300], 1, '#000000');
```

A correct answer to the question "Where to set the transform-origin" is `0% 50%`. This is easy to find out, when creating triangles with a line weight and semi-transparent color.

You can use `drawLine` to draw for example rectangles or circles too.

Comment: this is pretty awesome