# What does this angle derivation code do?

Tags: javascript, html, math, graphics

To cut a long story short - I needed some JS code to draw a vertical line on a webpage I'm developing. So I hunted around for some lightweight code (no frameworks or canvas) and found this:

[HTML line drawing without canvas (just JS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560302/html-line-drawing-without-canvas-just-js)

I dropped it into my page and it worked. Sort of. Even though I'd given it the co-ordinates to draw a vertical line, it decided that the line must be horizontal. The code in question appears to be this:

```
  var calc=Math.atan((ay-by)/(bx-ax));
  calc=calc*180/Math.PI;
```

If I force the angle to be zero, all is well (see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Wycott/7dynhhhu/2/) for a JSFiddle and try toggling the calcAngle flag).

How does this code decide which angle the line should be?

N.B. the JSFiddle is just a demonstration of the problem and not anything to do with the site itself so please don't get hung up on the specifics of this code.

Comment: You've passed the start and end points of a line. Those points make also the angle. Though `calc = Math.atan((ay-by)/(bx-ax));` should use `Math.atan2()` to resolve 90° and 270° angles too.

Comment: Btw. [this my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26606613/1169519) contains a simple `drawLine` function. Maybe you could use that? The code is commented, and uses simple `div`s and CSS, and doesn't need any libraries or frameworks.

Comment: Suggest you override calc with -90 or 270 and multiply by Math.PI/180.